# Change protractor debug port

Tags: debugging, protractor

Is there a way to change protractor's default debugger port 5858? Currently I'm using the following command to launch protractor:

```
$> protractor debug protractor.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port is hardcoded in several locations of the protractor code:

```
https://github.com/angular/protractor/search?q=5858&ref=cmdform
```

So i guess, you could [fill an issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/new) explaining your requirement, or you could [fork](https://github.com/angular/protractor/fork), modify protractor and make a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests).

Comment: Thanks for extensive answer, making pull request seems reasonable

Answer (score 3):

There's an optional parameter you can pass to pause to use a different port, e.g. `browser.pause(5859)` :

https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.pause